# Evaluate a Function Pointer on Structure Member Access in C?

Tags: c, patch, theory

I have a problem to solve that would basically just disappear if I could have a member of a struct evaluate to the result of a function when accessed. I don't think I've ever seen any examples of this kind of behavior -- In fact I have a suspicion that what I'm looking for would violate some deep rules of C if not programming in general. If that's the case I'd certainly appreciate hearing it from someone with a little more evidence/experience to explain why.

Here's some simplified code as an example:

```
/* state.c */

#include "state.h"

state_t state_ctx;
```

```
/* state.h */

typedef struct _state_t {
    foo_t foo;
}state_t;

extern state_t state_ctx;

#define ACCESS_STATE(x) (state_ctx.x)
```

```
/* main.c */

const bar_t bar{
    .baz = ACCESS_STATE(foo); // Types are compatible
}
```

In English there's a global state variable that has a convenient way to redefine access, and that access method is used inside an initializer list for a global variable in the .c file of interest.

That code works, but my mission is to allow to switch contexts from one state variable to another. I can easily change the state definitions to something like:

```
/* state.c */

#include "state.h"

state_t* p_current_state_ctx; // Now a pointer id's the current state structure
```

```
/* state.h */

typedef struct _state_t {
    baz_t foo;
}state_t;

extern state_t* p_current_state_ctx;

#define ACCESS_STATE(x) (p_current_state_ctx->x)
```

All I need to do to switch contexts is set the current state pointer. Nice. But one problem - the initializer lists require the ACCESS_STATE(x) macro to evaluate to a constant. I thought it was brilliant to define a function like:

```
foo_t func_to_get_foo( void ){
    return p_current_state_ctx->foo;
}
```

So that the `main.c` initializer could be re-written as:

```
/* main.c */

const bar_t bar{
    .baz = (foo_t)&func_to_get_foo; // Trying to get current state's foo
                                    // Obviously this cast isn't generally correct
                                    // and only compiles if the types are pointers
                                    // but still the behavior is wrong
}
```

Because the function pointer would be a constant expression. But as I wrote it out my heart deflated because I realized that of course now `baz` would just be the pointer to `func_to_get_foo` and not the value of foo like I had fantasized.

The actual program I'm working with is pretty complicated and I'm still learning it's ins and outs. I want to make as few modifications as I can while still getting the multi-state ability. There are a lot of instances of initializer list variables like the `bar` example so I'd prefer to avoid writing context-switching code for each one.

So if there was **some magic that could cause the result of `func_to_get_foo()` to appear as the result of accessing `bar.baz`** I'd be ecstatic. Does anyone have any advice on how to easily accomplish this?

If there's no way to do that then of course I'd be interested to hear some theory as to why... Or is it cut and dry 'thats just not a feature of C?'

And finally, if there's no clever trick then **what is the right way to change these variables that depend on the current state?** Will I need to write a function that sets up each and every one every time the context changes?

Comment: looks like you chose a wrong language. try c++.

Comment: What is wrong with defining `func_to_get_foo` to receive a `state_t*` parameter? _i.e_ `func_to_get_foo(&bar.baz)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming I'm following this correctly, `bar` is a global variable and `func_to_get_foo` isn't something you can manually fold. That does indeed make it tough. In fact, there's no way to do this in portable `c` code. In the old days, we put this stuff early in `main()` which worked well enough.

With `gcc` we can now use `attribute((constructor))`

```
bar_t bar; /* cannot declare this const as this might place it in readonly memory */
attribute((constructor))
static void init_bar(){
    bar.baz = func_to_get_foo();
}
```

Be careful; this only works if `state_t state_ctx;` was initialized with a `const` initializer otherwise this technique is utterly unreliable. Attribute initializers do run in an order, but it's not the order you want. In the second case we have to lean even farther on `gcc`'s extensions to replicate `c++`'s `iostream` magic as follows:

```
attribute((constructor))
static void init_bar(){
    init_state();
    bar.baz = func_to_get_foo();
}

/* ... */

state_t state;
static char state_initialized;
attribute((constructor))
void init_state()
{
    if (state_initialized) return;
    state_initialized = 1;
    /* do whatever to fill out state */
}
```

Comment: Interesting. You can also assign priorities greater than 100 (`101, 102, ...`) to the constructor/destructor sequence (gcc reserves 100 and below). There is a slightly more radical `elf_init` hack on Linux that allows you to write the name of the initializer function directly to the `.init` section of the executable using inline assembly which is called before all other constructors that would be a good place to ensure the global is initialized -- but that would be even less portable.

Comment: If _I_ understand correctly the `attribute((constructor))` signals the compiler to execute functions in the initializer list? Maybe one day I'll find a place to use that... I kind of expected you to say that it is impossible in portable C. Anyway that's certainly some neat stuff -- thanks for sharing!